# PayPal API Secret key security

Tags: security, paypal, client, secret-key

The developer of my web site asked me for the Client ID and Secret Key to integrate the PayPal Payment.
My Question is: If I provide these credentials can they withdraw funds from my account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API credentials cannot be used to withdraw funds, unless both of the following are true

- You have contacted PayPal to request the Mass Pay / Payouts feature be enabled for your live PayPal business account. This is rare, approval and the feature enablement is only granted for specific business needs to pay out money.
- The REST App that client id/secret correspond to also have the "Payouts" permission checked in the App settings. This *is* checked by default under "Other features", so if you are paranoid just uncheck it and save, then send them the client id and secret.

Comment: Thank you so much Preston PHX!! I deselected the Payout option in the Other features. Thanks again!